# Do I need to cut this shop vac hose adapter when I use it?

Tags: hose, adapter, vacuum

[image]

I am using this with Rigind vacuum and a router table. The router table adapter is the size of the second section in the picture, counting from the right side bottom up.

The vacuum is struggling because its hose diameter is reduced from 2" to whatever the end diameter is and it is not very effective at collecting dust in this situation.

So do I need to cut this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are supposed to cut this at the point which gives you the correct diameter.

Collecting dust from tools requires large amounts of airflow (cfm) and static pressures can be very low and still effective. In your case, you will have high pressure but low airflow due to that restriction.

Also helps to ensure there are minimum bends and turns in your hose and keep the hose as short as possible.

Comment: Makes sense but then what is the point to sell an all in one when you can sell just individual adapters.